# Python with as statement not assigning reference

Tags: python

The with statement does not appear to be returning the correct reference, instead it returns None.

```
class test():
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass
    def __enter__(self):
        print('entered')
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        print('exit')

with test() as t:
    print(type(t))
    print('inside')
```

Output:

```
>entered
><class 'NoneType'>
>inside
>exit
```

I would like `t` to be the  reference to the `test` instance, not `None`.

Python V3.10

Comment: The value returned from the `__enter__` method is assigned to the name after `as` - return `self` from the `__enter__` method

Answer (score 0):

```
def __enter__(self):
    return self
```

The solution is to return a reference from `__enter__`